# Will I damage the laptop if I always use a travel adapter to charge it?

Tags: laptop, battery, power, charging, charger

This scenario could happen if I bought a laptop in one country but later moved to live in another country with a different power standard. Will it be safe to just add a travel adapter on the plug and charge the laptop? I worry about potential long-term damage to the battery. Or would it be better to try to contact the local support for this brand of laptop and buy a charger with natively local plug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most laptop power bricks work with a wide range of voltages (most say Input:100~240v), read the label on your laptop power brick, look at "input" section The travel adapter is nothing more than a gender changer for the wall socket. If your power brick has this input variable voltage then you are safe to use the adapter.

Example Label, look at bottom left corner of image for Input voltage

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The power adapter of the laptop has a label on it: in that label it's printed the lower and upper AC voltage to which the power adapter can be safely connected (110VAC to 240VAC, also for the AC frequency, usually 50 and 60 Hz).
Unless you plug the cord in the wrong outlet, you should be "safe" with a travel adapter.
As a better solution, buy a power adpater for the AC the country you are in (but in most cases, the power adapter it's the same for all the world: only the power cord is different).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a right or wrong answer here.

If you moved to that country, it would be best to purchase the correct AC adapter for your laptop. This lessens the chances of using the wrong connection and damaging your equipment.

If you choose to continue using the travel adapter, as long as it is providing the correct conversion for your existing AC requirements, then there is no harm. The only suggestion I would make here is to spend the money on a good quality travel adapter.